# How to convert PyObject to java boolean type

Tags: java, python, casting, boolean, jython

I would like to cast org.python.core.PyObject to java.lang.Boolean.
Something similar to:

```
boolean i = ((Boolean) PyObject).booleanValue();
```

Comment: What is your intended usage? i.e why are you needing this

Comment: I am using Jython to call a python method from a java class. That method returns PyObject. i.e. boolean, integer, double I would like to be able to convert them to the relevant java types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the following:

```
PyObject obj = interpreter.eval("True");
boolean i = ((PyInteger) obj).asInt() != 0;
```

Comment: Does this answer mean that Jython returns True as an integer back to Java?  What about String, Float, Double and other basic scalar types?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Python standard object interface **nonzero** method:

```
PyObject obj = interpreter.eval("True");
boolean i = obj.__nonzero__();
```

(it's called "nonzero" because it existed before Python had a boolean type and Guido's ways are mysterious sometimes)