# How to call method of python file using java

Tags: java, python

My python File has the code as:

```
class myPythonClass():
def abc(self):
    print "calling abc"
    tmpb = {}
    tmpb = {'status' : 'SUCCESS'}
    return tmpb
```

and my java code is:

```
 PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
             interpreter.execfile("/home/Desktop/abc.py");
             interpreter.set("myvariable", file1);
             PyObject answer = interpreter.eval("myPythonClass().abc(myvariable)");
             System.out.println(answer.toString());
```

In my python file if i dont give brackets for class name then my java code executes python file.
But if my python file starts with `class myPythonClass():` then its not working.
Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: "its not working". How? Any error messages? Weird behavior? Unexpected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try identing:

```
class myPythonClass():
    def abc(self):
        print "calling abc"
        tmpb = {}
        tmpb = {'status' : 'SUCCESS'}
        return tmpb
```

It seems it isn't indented so it doesn't becomes part of the `class` declaration and Python doesn't likes that.
But I know nothing about Java so...

Also try starting with a comment (`#comment`) and see if it works.

PS: Sorry if I wasn't clear or sure, I just can't comment with the reputation I has.

Comment: No its indented properly at my side

Comment: Its saying source file attachment does not contain file_bullitin class

Comment: My bad. It seems it don't have a built-in class file (my guess). But as I said, I know nothing about Java.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a look at [how-to-call-a-python-method-from-a-java-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381906/how-to-call-a-python-method-from-a-java-class).

Until your python code is correct and intended correctly. If I read the [docs](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) right, you can just use the [eval](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#eval%28org.python.core.PyObject%29) function: :)

```
interpreter.execfile("/path/to/python_file.py");
PyDictionary result = interpreter.eval("myPythonClass().abc()");
```

Or if you want to get a string:

```
PyObject str = interpreter.eval("repr(myPythonClass().abc())");
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

If you want to supply it with some input from Java variables, you can use set beforehand and than use that variable name within your Python code:

```
interpreter.set("myvariable", Integer(21));
PyObject answer = interpreter.eval("'the answer is: %s' % (2*myvariable)");
System.out.println(answer.toString());
```